# How to find the largest value for each row and save it into an extra column

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with several columns, which looks as follows

```
ID1     ID2    ID3
 1       2      3
 6       5      4
 7       8      9
```

I would like to add one extra column, which stores the largest value for row. How to do that in Excel?

Comment: You should look into the Max formula

Comment: I don't think its programmatical question off topic

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the data you have is in Columns A through C and rows 1 through 4, put the following formula in column D, and copy it down as far as necessary:
    =max(A2:C2)

Answer (score 0):

In the extra column (say D1) put :  =max(A1:C1)

You can paste it downward.

Comment: I don't think this is what he is asking for. He wants the max of each row